# Predict using MS SCOM 2012 R2 Data

Tags: analytics, scom

Has anybody tried to predict application or server failures using MS SCOM 2012 R2 Data? We would like to perform following tasks with the data and were wondering if somebody has already done this, we could use the guidance:

1. Predict whether an application or server is risking failure.
2. Perform Root Cause Analysis on failures for quick resolution of issues so that support engineers get guidance on where to go next.
3. Perform some form of clustering so that we can say that when Application A fails, B and C tend to fail right after also.

Our specific questions are:

1. What data/features did you have to use to build your predictive model (Events, Alerts, State, Performance)?
2. Which algorithms did you find most useful?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look if Operational Insights can fullfill this requirement. 
There is a Capacity Intelligence Pack which promises predicitve analitics. 
https://preview.opinsights.azure.com/